# DataGridView: programmatically select/highlight entire column on button click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to programmatically select/highlight entire column on button click to let users know what they searched.

[This is what currently happens on button click ("GO" button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIL7f.png)
but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZcCW.png) is what I need to happen.

I have tried these so far to no avail:

`DataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect
DataGridView2.Columns(2).Selected = True`

*Doing so gave me this error:* `DataGridView control's SelectionMode cannot be set to FullColumnSelect while it has a column with SortMode set to DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic.`

I also tried to simply select the whole column. No error, but it didn't work.

`DataGridView2.Columns(2).Selected = True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [thread](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/winforms-grids/32734-column-selection-datagridview.html). I modified the code like so:

```
Dim row As DataGridViewRow
For Each row In DataGridView2.Rows
    row.Cells(1).Selected = True
Next
```

and placed it inside `Private Sub Button1_Click`

I noticed that the first cell is automatically selected. [This](https://begeeben.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/not-to-select-the-first-row-in-datagridview-by-default/) solved that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `Selected` property of each cell in the column.

Comment: @austin Loop through each row, set the desired cell's `Selected` property to `True`.

Comment: Ah, okay. I changed the keywords I use to search for an answer to my problem.. I finally found some similar threads. Thank you